# Basic alerts from node.js

Tags: ajax, node.js

I have a form where a user enters their email, password and class. I send the user the HTML file from node.js using:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/Login-Signup.html'));
});
```

I think get the variables from the form using:

```
var email = req.body.email;
var password = req.body.password;
var cpassword = req.body.cpassword;
var userclass = req.body.userclass;
```

This is how my HTML form is set out:

```
<form method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="formTitle">Account Sign Up</div>

                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" />

                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" />

                <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id= "cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm password"/>

                <label for="class">Class:</label>
                <input id="text" id= "class" name="userclass" placeholder="Enter your class"/>

                <input type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="/" value="Submit Details">

            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

When the values have been entered, the variables must pass a few checks to see if they are valid. They are laid out as so:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    function emailCheck(email){
        //when theres an error: console.log(error), and return false
    }

    function passCheck(password){
        //when theres an error: console.log(error), and return false
    }

    if (passCheck == true && emailCheck == true){
        //enter user into database
    }
}
```

When the email or password is not valid (to my checks) I want an alert box to appear, displaying the problem. I've looked into using AJAX, experimenting with the code but nothing seems to work for me. Is it the way I'm collecting the variables from the HTML? Is it how my get/post commands are laid out?

Thanks in advance.

PS; I am using express.

Comment: You could use flash messages for responding to such requests: https://github.com/expressjs/flash

Comment: You should run your validations before you send the page, you can use AJAX to validate the fields entered as the user fills them out so by the time the user gets to the "Send" button you know if the fields are Ok or not.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the Ajax (Jquery) post and `res.send` to get the result in the front-end:

**Front-end:**

```
        <fieldset>
            <div class="formTitle">Account Sign Up</div>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" />

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" />

            <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id= "cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm password"/>

            <label for="class">Class:</label>
            <input id="text" id= "class" name="userclass" placeholder="Enter your class"/>

            <input type="button" onclick="save();" value="Submit Details">

        </fieldset>
```

**JQuery Ajax:**

```
function save(){
  var data = {};
  data.email = document.getElementById("email");
  data.password = document.getElementById("password");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    datatype: "json",
    url: '/',
    success: function(returns){
        if (returns) 
            alert("User save");
        else
            alert("Error: user not save");
    }
  });
```

**Node.js:**

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    function emailCheck(email){
        //when theres an error: console.log(error), and return false
    }

    function passCheck(password){
        //when theres an error: console.log(error), and return false
    }

    if (passCheck == true && emailCheck == true){
        res.send(true); // if ok. You can get the res.send in the success ajax event.
    }
}
```

Remove the `form` and get the values through javascript.

Comment: Should my node.js pick up the variables in the same way?

Comment: It just seems to completely skip the AJAX and just clears everything only saying "true" or whatever is in the res.send().

Comment: Yes, you populate the variables in the `var data = {}` and `data.email = document.getElementById`. When you post, the json `data` will contains the values.

Comment: Sorry for mistakes, but this behavior is caused because the form submit. You need to take off the `form` and call the function `save()` through the event `onclick` of the button.

Comment: So far, all the values now display in the URL like so `http://localhost:3000/?email=&password=`. It seems like the app.post() isn't even running to receive these values.